# Mockito in SpringBoot v. constructor injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I use SpringBoot 3.x.
I have a service with three dependencies. I tried inject them via the constructor like this:

```
@Service
class MyService
  private final DependencyOne one;
  private final DependencyTwo two;
  private final DependencyThree three;

  @Autowired
  public MyClass(DependencyOne one, DependencyTwo two, DependencyThree three) {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
    this.three = three;
  }
  ...
```

Then I have Mockito tests like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock private DependencyOne one;
    @Mock private DependencyTwo two;
    @Mock private DependencyThree three;
    @InjectMocks private MyService tested;

    @Test
    void testA()...
    @Test
    void testB()...
```

Now, in this configuration, `testB` fails when I run the whole test class via mvn:

```
mvn test -Dtest="MyServiceTest"
```

but succeedes when I run only `testB`:

```
mvn test -Dtest="MyServiceTest#testB"
```

When I use field injection instead of the constructor one, all tests are green.

```
@Service
class MyService
  @Autowired private DependencyOne one;
  @Autowired private DependencyTwo two;
  @Autowired private DependencyThree three;
  ...
```

Am I missing something in the test configuration?

Comment: Could you tell what is the error on `testB` when it is run with the whole test class via mvn ?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but sounds a bit as if the required mocks for `testA`, `testC`, etc are interfering with the required mocks for `testB`. You can try with [`@DirtiesContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html).

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens There is just assertions whether resulting collection is empty or not. What I want to know is, why mockito treats field and constructor injections differently.

Comment: That's strange indeed... If you can share a minimal reproducible example, I'd be happy to help investigate more on this one.